# How to show an object class in a treeview

Tags: c#, .net

I have an XML file and I save it as a object class. After some computation on the object class some fields including `color` will be changed. After that I want to show the result as a `treeview` in a **GUI**. First, I want to know if it is possible to show in a `treeview`? What I need to have to show the object class as a treeview?

If so then I want to show the `treeview` with the `name` field in `action` class. Also, I want to color the `treenodes` with the `color` that I have assigned in the computation process.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class action
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("obj")]
    public List<obj> Obj { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("onproc")]
    public List<onproc> Onproc { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("Color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

and the required class for above class are as:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class obj
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("dir")]
    public Collection<dir> DirList { get; set; }
}
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class onproc
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class dir
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("dir")]
    public Collection<dir> DirList { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the Treeview? In a Browser?

Comment: @JeroenHeier No in a GUI which has a treeview part in it.

Comment: Is there anyone who could please help me? Thanks